# Property X does not exist on type X while mocking a function

Tags: typescript

```
import { IListItem } from './IListItem';

export default class SPHttpClient  {

    private static _items: IListItem[] = [{ Title: 'Mock List', PercentComplete: 11, Id: 1 },
                                        { Title: 'Mock List 2', PercentComplete: 61, Id: 2 },
                                        { Title: 'Mock List 3', PercentComplete: 36, Id: 3 }];


    public static readonly configurations: mockConfig = {v1: 'value'};

    public static get(restUrl: string, options?: any): Promise<IListItem[]> {
    return new Promise<IListItem[]>((resolve) => {
            resolve(SPHttpClient._items);
        });
    }
}

export class mockConfig {
    public static readonly v1: any = '1';
}
```

I need to mock SPHttpClient and for some reason I am getting: Property 'v1' does not exist on type 'mockConfig'.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? I thought assigning mockConfig the value of an object with the property v1 would have solved the issue, but I am still getting the same error.

```
private async getToDosAsync():Promise<any> {
    let items=[];
    await this.props.spHttpClient.get(`${this.props.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ToDo')/items`,
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1).then(async(response)=>{
      if(response.ok)
      {
        await response.json().then((data)=>{
          items = data.value;
        });
      }
    });

    this.setState({items:items});
    return items;
}
```

This is where I am calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static readonly v1: any = '1';
```

The problem is that you've defined v1 to be a static property. In other words, it's a property of a class, not a property of an instance of the class. Then you define SPHttpClient as having an instance of that class. You did sneak a v1 onto that instance, but as this is not part of the type, you get an error when you try to access it.

Instead, make the property non static, either like this:

```
export class mockConfig {
    public readonly v1: any = '1';
}
```

or like this

```
export interface mockConfig {
  v1: any,
}
```

---

P.S. This isn't directly related to your question, but i have to comment on your getToDosAsync function. You're getting no benefit out of your use of async/await. You keep calling .then to create a promise, then awaiting the promise you just created, then not using the value that would have been returned from await. Your exact same code, adjusted to use async/await as intended, looks like this:

```
private async getToDosAsync():Promise<any> {
  let items = [];
  const response = await this.props.spHttpClient.get(
    `${this.props.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ToDo')/items`,
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1
  );
  if (response.ok) {
    const data = await response.json();
    items = data.value;
  }

  this.setState({items:items});
  return items;
}
```